# How to get picture taken date from Instagram api on Android?

Tags: android, instagram

In my Android application I need to get date of a picture from Instagram api. Instagram return some value from created_time tag which not in milliseconds format. If I convert that value to date, java return invalid date. How can I get correct date from the  "created_time" tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instagram return the date in `Unix time stamp` so that I got invalid date while converting. The solution is we need to `multiple 1000 with created_time` tag value.

This is the code:

```
String x = "1414678736"; // created_time tag value goes here.
long foo = **Long.parseLong(x)*1000;**
Date date = new Date(foo);
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```